# Syntax error with MariaDB Involving Server Version

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mariadb

I have been running a LiveSite website now for almost a year without any problems, but have for the last 1-2 weeks get this error:

> Error: Query failed.
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'rows, cols, informatio' at line 14

I have submitted a support ticket, but they have helped.

I have looked around my cPanel settings in phpMyAdmin at the database settings, but really don't know where to look.

I am using ( i.e. the web hosting company I use):

Database server

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server connection: SSL is not being used
  ￼
- Server version: 10.3.14-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
- Protocol version: 10
- User: edmbeats@localhost
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Web server

- cpsrvd 11.78.0.24
- Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
- PHP extension: mysqli, curl, mbstring
- PHP version: 7.2.7

phpMyAdmin

- Version information: 4.8.3

Nothing really, need to know where to go to fix this. I have not changed any thing at the site for 8 months, no updates, no setting changes. I am not sure if the hosting company has updated their DB programs, and caused this. There is a newer version of LiveSite the 2019 version that is newer than  the 2017 version I am using, but the LiveSite does not support an AutoUpdate for the 2017 version within the hosting platform.

NA

Comment: Release date of 10.3.14 is 2019-04-02. So there must have been an update in the last 8 months. Check if MariaDB has introduced new (reserved) keywords like `ROWS`.

Comment: Please consider using code blocks or other formatting tools to make your question easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/ says the keyword `ROWS` was added as a reserved word in MariaDB 10.2.4.

You can use reserved words in your SQL statements by delimiting them with back-ticks:

```
... `rows`, cols, informatio...
```

So you'll have to edit your application code that runs that query, which means you'll have to figure out exactly which query caused the error.

It's a good practice to avoid using reserved words for your table and column identifiers. If the LiveSite code is using a reserved word, they should be made aware that they need to correct this, or else put back-ticks around table and column identifiers that conflict with reserved words. I suggest you contact them with a support request.

Comment: IS there an easy way to determine which file I need to add the back-ticks to? I have looked into config, init, settings, welcome, class, css files and cannot find the offending statement....

Comment: SQL statements come from your code files, not HTML or CSS files. But the SQL might not appear literally in your code files either, if you use some framework that generates SQL for you. I don't know anything about LiveSite. You might want to contact LiveSite support.